# How to save org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector in dataframe to cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a requirement to save dataframe which contains org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector in one of the column. While creating the table in cassandra from the dataframe, it is throwing error.

```
java.lang.Exception: Cassandra Writer Failed. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.unsupportedType$1(ColumnType.scala:132)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.fromSparkSqlType(ColumnType.scala:155)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DataFrameColumnMapper$$anonfun$1.apply(DataFrameColumnMapper.scala:18)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DataFrameColumnMapper$$anonfun$1.apply(DataFrameColumnMapper.scala:16)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DataFrameColumnMapper.newTable(DataFrameColumnMapper.scala:16)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.TableDef$.fromDataFrame(Schema.scala:206)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save the binary value of this type, you'll need to just convert it to a Byte array then save it to a blob column.

If you want to save it as a set of values you'll need to do the appropriate conversion to a Scala collection.